# Как с помощью XPath получить значение между двумя тэгами

Tags: xpath

Есть *xml* вида:

```
<node>
    some_text_1

    <sub_node_1>
       some_text_2
       <sub_node_x>
       ...
       </sub_node_x>
    </sub_node_1>

    some_text_3

    <sub_node_2>
       some_text_4
       <sub_node_x>
       ...
       </sub_node_x>
    </sub_node_2>

    some_text_5
</node>
```

Как с использованием *XPath* получить значение текста `"some_text_3"` ?

Только *XPath* без кода на ЯП - решение в одну строку вида `//node/???/text()`.

Comment: Это именно текст или набор тэгов? - Это совершенно разные вопросы и ответы

Comment: Это обычный текст

Comment: Мой ответ продолжает работать :)

Comment: Суть проблемы была в самом вопросе - "между двумя тэгами". Пример же описывал один из многих сценариев. Ваше решение работает для конкретного примера, представленного ранее. Изменил содержание примера, что бы оно полностью описывало проблему (суть не изменилась). Для него Ваш ответ не работает :(

Comment: Я обновил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//node/text()
```

вы получите набор из трех строк, поскольку текст разорван дочерними нодами

```
Text=''
Text='some_text_2'
Text=''
```

**UPDATE** Все, что я вам могу предложить, это

```
//node/text()[2]
```

но это, если он всегда второй фрагмент текста.

**update2** К*омментарий к ответу Дмитрия*

Не знал, что text() можно рассматривать как самостоятельную единицу, а не свойство ноды - спасибо Дмитрию. Это, действительно, дает возможность правильного решения задачи. В его ответе приведено первое приближение.Для общего случая будем думать, что нужный нам текст мжт быть рассечен другими тэгами, например, так

```
 </sub_node_1>
   some_text<br/>3
 <sub_node_2>
```

Его решение даст только `some_text`. Чтобы действительно найти весь текст между заданными тэгами, выражение должно быть чуть сложнее

```
//node/sub_node_1/following-sibling::text()[following-sibling::sub_node_2]
```

Для примера выше оно даст

```
Text='some_text'
Text='3'
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но в исходной задаче внутри тэгов sub_node_1 и sub_node_2 может находиться другой текст и другие ноды. Ключевой момент, что нужен именно текст some_text, без содержимого указанных нод.

Comment: Удачи! Не забудьте принять ответ :)

Comment: Приношу свои извинения за неполное описание проблемы.

Comment: А каково полное?

Comment: номер фрагмента заранее неизвестен, но ваш ответ позволил найти приемлемое решение (не знал что индексатор можно применить к text())

Comment: @Дмитрий Я написал в своем ответе комментарий к вашему :)

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Рад был помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Для получения текста между требуемым тэгом и следующим после него, можно использовать следующий XPath запрос:

```
    //node/sub_node_1/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Интерпретация запроса - взять следующий за sub_node_1 тэгом текст, находящийся с ним на одном уровне.